# cannot upgrade kernel (grubby fatal error: unable to find a suitable template)

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, grub

I have an appliance (read: a PC in a rackmount chassis which sits in the rack and does its job for years without anyone really paying it much attention until it dies) running CentOS 5.4.  Trying to upgrade the kernel to the latest 5.x release (2.6.18 build 406) and running into this error message.

I have read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712084/grubby-fatal-error-unable-to-find-a-suitable-template, but that Q offered no explanation or solutions.

I have also read https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=166217 and tried that out as well... no luck either.

I REALLY do not want to have to concoct some hackish script wrapper for a kernel upgrade to do something which the tool is supposed to do so I'm hopeful there is a solution to this.

My grub file resides in /boot/grub (grub.conf).  There is a symlink in /boot/grub/grub pointing to it, as there is also a symlink in /etc likewise pointing to it.

The actual grub.conf (sans comments for brevity):

```
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,2)/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.18-348.16.1.el5)
    root (hd0,5)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-348.16.1.el5 ro root=LABEL=ROOT
    initrd /initrd-2.6.18-348.16.1.el5.img
```

The output of the kernel rpm running the post install script, new-kernel-pkg (I added the quotes around the titles so I could rerun the command):

```
/sbin/grubby --add-kernel=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18-406.el5 --initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.18-406.el5.img --copy-default --make-default --title "CentOS (2.6.18-406.el5)" --args=root=LABEL=ROOT  --remove-kernel=TITLE="CentOS (2.6.18-406.el5)"
```

It all looks valid to me.  I just don't understand what the grubby tool is expecting to find in the grub.conf and what mine is failing to provide to satisfy it.  Anyone?

**Note**: If I mod the above script to add `--bad-image-okay` to the grubby commandline, it will work as I would expect: the new kernel is added to the grub.conf file and it's all correct... but that option is supposed to ignore errors and the like, so, what is wrong with my config, or more accurately, what error did I tell grubby to ignore?